# GrayScale Shader not working and removing alpha rendering

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I am trying to develop a shader that's just a simple grayscale shader. The game is running, but the shader does not have any effect and any textures that were before rendered with 0.5 Alpha now look like they were rendered with full alpha.

Grayscale.vert

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

    void main(){

        gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
        v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
        v_color = a_color;

}
```

Grayscale.frag

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#else
#define highp;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const vec3 grayScaleMultiplier = vec3(0.299,0.587,0.114);

void main(){
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture,v_texCoord);
    vec3 gray = vec3(dot(texColor.rgb,grayScaleMultiplier));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gray.r,gray.g,gray.b,texColor.a);
}
```

And how the Shader is applied

```
shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/grayscale.vert"),Gdx.files.internal("shaders/grayscale.frag"));
        testBatch.setShader(shaderProgram);

        if(!shaderProgram.isCompiled()) {
            System.out.println(shaderProgram.getLog());
        }
```

My Render Calls

```
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(1,1,1,255);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    mapLayerManager.render();

   batch.begin();

  for(AbstractEnemy enemy : allEnemys){
        enemy.render(batch);
  }
  batch.end();

  lightManager.render(batch);

  shapeRenderer.begin();
  shapeRenderer.setColor(0,0,0,100);
  shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
  for(AbstractEnemy enemy : allEnemys){
      enemy.render(shapeRenderer);
  }
  shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
  shapeRenderer.setColor(0,0,0,255);
  shapeRenderer.end();

  batch.begin();
  player.render(batch);
  batch.end();

   world.step(1/45f,6,2);
```

I don't get any compile errors and I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: THe GL state at the time of the draw calls is totally unclear, so it is impossible to find out what exactly is going on.

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I dont quite understand what i could post? my rendering calls are the usual clear screen batch.beginn , then the rendering and batch.render at the end

Comment: You don't happen to have two different sprite batches, do you? I see you applying the shader to `testBatch` but drawing with `batch`.

Comment: oh no its the same batch. i just copied the render methods together since i have it structured into a level system